# Flavours of unix

Tags: unix, operating-system

I'm a student and this question came in my exam and made me a little confused after I searched online. -

Which of the following is not a flavour of UNIX ?

1. IRIX
2. AIX
3. BSD
4. MAC

I think it should be BSD but I'm confused because when I searched for answers , all seem to be valid flavours . Please tell me which one is not a flavour in case one of the above options is close to the answer.

Comment: @Satya MacOS X is based on FreeBSD kernel and a large portions of BSD userland. However you might be right if the question is too old.

Comment: oh mea culpa @Kworr removing my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet @Satya is right and right answer is a MAC. All other systems are born to be UNIX while Mac switched long ago (not so long if we are talking about exams and books).